# Incrementing variables in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and am trying to create a script that goes through a csv file (simple name,value csv) and loads each new line in it as a variable and then runs a function against that set of variables.

I've had success at getting it to work for 1 variable by using the following code snippet:

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\something\mylist.csv | ForEach-Object {
    New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Force
    }
```

My csv looks like this:

```
name,value
RegKey1,"Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\LanmanWorkstation"
```

Basically it's a list of registry keys each named as RegKey# and then the path of that reg key is the intended value of the variable.

I'm currently playing around with the "Test-Path" cmdlet that just prints out true/false if the passed reg-key exists and then just prints out some text based on if it found the reg key or not.
That snippet looks like so:

```
Test-Path $RegKey1
IF ($LASTEXITCODE=0) {
    Write-Output "It worked"
    }
else    {
    Write-Output "It didn't work"
    }
```

This works fine however what I'm trying to achieve is for powershell to run this cmdlet against each of the lines in the csv file - basically checking each reg key in it and then doing whatever specified to it.
What I'm trying to avoid is declaring hundreds of variables for every regkey I plan on using but instead have this one function that just runs through the csv and every time it runs, it increments the number next to the variable's name - RegKey1,RegKey2,RegKey3 etc.

Let me know if there's a way to do this in powershell or a better way of approaching this altogether. I also apologize in advance if I've not provided enough info, please do let me know.

Comment: I would expect the `ForEach-Object{}` loop to go through the CSV file. Why does your first code snippet not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place your `if` statement in the `Foreach-Object` loop. This will also only work, if your variable all get the same name of `$RegKey`. To incriment, you may use the `for` loop.

```
Import-Csv -Path C:\something\mylist.csv | ForEach-Object {
    New-Variable -Name $_.Name -Value $_.Value -Force
IF (Test-Path $RegKey1) {
    Write-Output "It worked"
    }
else    {
    Write-Output "It didn't work"
    }    

    }
```

The `if` statement returns a boolean value of `$true`, or `$false`. So theres no need to use `$LastExitCode` by placing the `Test-Path` as the condition to evaluate for.

Alternatively, you can use the `Foreach` loop to accomplish the same thing here:

```
 $CSV = Import-Csv -Path C:\something\mylist.csv
    Foreach($Key in $CSV.Value){
        $PathTest = Test-Path -Path $Key
            if($PathTest) {
                Write-Output "It worked"
                                } else {
                Write-Output "It didn't work"
                                }    
                    }
```

By iterating(reading through the list 1 at a time) through the csv only selecting the value(Reg Path), we can test against that value by assigning its value to the `$PathTest` Variable, to be evaluated in your `if` statement just like above; theres also no need to assign it to a variable and we can just use the `Test-Path` in your `if` statement like we did above as well for the same results.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I don't come from a coding background so I'm still learning the concepts but this explanation covered precisely what I was looking for. Thank you again !

Comment: Good luck in your project!